# $abcd=6(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)(1-d)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Positive integers $a \geqslant b \geqslant c \geqslant d$ satisfy:

$$abcd=6(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)(1-d)$$

$1.$ Prove that $d=2$

$2.$ Find all possible values of $a,b,c$.

What I know:

Since $x$ and $x-1$ are relatively prime for all positive integers $x$ :

$$\gcd(a,1-a)=\gcd(b,1-b)=\gcd(c,1-c)=\gcd(d,1-d)=1$$

Comment: Calculus is not an appropriate tag for this question

Comment: What's the source of this problem, please?

Comment: a school entrance exam

Comment: What kind of school, please. A current school entrance exam?

Comment: a high school entrance exam

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can rewrite this as:
$$\prod_{cyc} \frac{a}{a-1} =6$$
We clearly have $a \geqslant b \geqslant c \geqslant d > 1$. Also, we can see that $\frac{x}{x-1}$ is a decreasing function. If $d>2$ then, 
$$\prod_{cyc} \frac{a}{a-1} < (1.5)^4<6$$
This forces $d=2$. We now have:
$$\frac{a}{a-1} \cdot  \frac{b}{b-1} \cdot \frac{c}{c-1}=3$$
Similarly assume that $c>3$. We have $(1.33)^3<3$ which is a contradiction and we will then have $c \in {2,3}$.

If $c=3$, we will have:
$$\frac{a}{a-1} \cdot \frac{b}{b-1} = 2$$
Continuing in the similar fashion, we can force $b=3$ which yields $a=4$ and thus we have $(a, b, c, d) =(4,3,3,2)$.

If $c=2$, we will have:
$$\frac{a}{a-1} \cdot \frac{b}{b-1} =\frac{3}{2}$$
Since $\frac{a}{a-1}>1$ we have $\frac{b}{b-1}<\frac{3}{2}$ which gives $b>3$. If $b>5$, we get $(1.2)^2<1.5$. We thus need to have $3<b \leqslant 5$. Although $b=3$ doesn't give integer $a$, the other cases gives us $(a, b, c, d) =(9,4,2,2)$ and $(a, b, c, d) =(6,5,2,2)$.

Comment: In the case $c=d=2$ there is also $(6,5,2,2).$ Beautiful solution! +1.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thank you, I forgot $b=5$. Made the necessary edit.